# CSS text paragraph animation keeps slowing after running one after another paragraph

Tags: css-animations

I'm new with CSS animation, been watching from some tutorials, but still need lot of practices and confused how it works with "steps(60, end)".
All I know if I put 60 then the text is quicker.

So I have 5 paragraphs which I want to run 1 paragraph each time after another for  a quick run like 1 sec, it was working, but after the third, fourth and fifth paragraph, it's getting slower, if I add "animation: text-2 2s steps(60, end);" for each paragraph, it's running quick, but it doesn't run one after another. What am I doing wrong here?

```css
.p1 {
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 80px;
  border: 1px solid green;
  animation: text-1 1s steps(60, end);
}

.p2 {
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100px;
  border: 1px solid green;
  animation: text-2 2s steps(60, end);
}

.p3 {
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 110px;
  border: 1px solid green;
  animation: text-2 4s steps(60, end);
}

.p4 {
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 80px;
  border: 1px solid green;
  animation: text-2 8s steps(60, end);
}

.p5 {
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 82px;
  border: 1px solid green;
  animation: text-2 16s steps(60, end);
}


@keyframes text-1 {
  from {
    width: 0;
  }
}

@keyframes text-2 {
  0% {
    width: 0;
  }
  50% {
    width: 0;
  }
  100% {
    width: 100;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
        <div class="first-row">
          <p class="p1">Paragraph 1</p>
          <div class="p2">
            <img src="#">
            <span>Paragraph 2</span>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="second-row">
          <p class="p3">Paragraph 3 <span> text</span></p>
          <p class="p4">Paragraph 4</p>
        </div>
        <div class="third-row">
          <p class="p5">Paragraph 5 <span>text</span></p>
        </div
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

//You can try this css code

```
.p1 {
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 80px;
  border: 1px solid green;
  animation: text-1 1s steps(60, end);
}

.p2 {
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100px;
  border: 1px solid green;
  animation: text-2 2s steps(120, end);
}

.p3 {
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 110px;
  border: 1px solid green;
  animation: text-2 3s steps(180, end);
}

.p4 {
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 80px;
  border: 1px solid green;
  animation: text-2 4s steps(240, end);
}

.p5 {
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 82px;
  border: 1px solid green;
  animation: text-2 5s steps(300, end);
}


@keyframes text-1 {
  from {
    width: 0;
  }
}

@keyframes text-2 {
  0% {
    width: 0;
  }
  50% {
    width: 0;
  }
  100% {
    width: 100;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried it, text is quicker, but it doesn't work as I expected, the text is still slow at the end and running before other paragraph finish.

Comment: this it fact here